# Configuring IPv6 network

Tags: ios, iphone, ipv6

I need to test my application on IPv6 network on iPhone. As far as I have learned, I have several options:

1. Share IPv6 Internet via iMac as described in [this](http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-how-to-test-your-app-for-ipv6-compatibility/) tutorial; though when I tried to follow the steps there on an MacBook Air connected by bluetooth to an iPhone with turned on 3G there was no "Create NAT64 Network" checkbox for step 7 - do I nessesarely need to be connected via cabel or I need a stationary iMac?
2. Configurate IPv6 wi-fi on a router; though as far as I have learned to do this I need some special router that supports IPv6 and my Internet provider should be able to give me IPv6 connection. Is this correct?

Are there other, maybe easier ways to simulate IPv6 on an iPhone? How do I tell router that supports IPv6 from the one that does not?

Answer (score 0):

I know its a bit late, yet it might help someone. You can create an ipV6 network via step 1 described. The trick is, at the time of clicking on BluetoothPAN option, you should press the **option(ALT) key** in the keyboard. Then **Create NAT64 Network** checkbox will be displayed at the bottom. This is the same case for WIFI & Ethernet too